# Installing a Hard Drive to access existing files

Tags: hard-drive

All I want to do is get access to a hard drive to remove the files but the drive is not recognised by Ubuntu. I have no idea of what version but I have just downloaded the OS from what was stated as the official site and I assume it's the latest version.
I have tried to use ask but all I find is that I need to enter a whole heap of code that I know nothing about. The last Ask Ubuntu I tried mentioned something about a disk utility which looked promising but I couldn't find it.
I am totally new to anything Linux and would really appreciate it if someone could give me some very basic detailed instructions, (For Dummies), on how to do this.
Just in case it's needed the drive details are:
Western Digital WD7500AACS

Any assistance gratefully accepted.

Nick

Comment: Is the drive externally or internally mounted?

Comment: ...and what type? NTFS? EXT4? What is it used for, from what OS? Is it mounted at all? :)

Comment: It's out of a WD My Book World Edition 2, network drive and I have been told that I need to use Linux to access the files which have been saved to the drive from Windows 7. It is an internal drive connected directly to the motherboard via Sata cable

Comment: If files have been saved to the drive from Windows then safe bet is it is NTFS. Do you know how to open a command promt ? If you do, lets do 2 things to start. First thing, with this new drive disconnected, type 'sudo fdisk -l' (without the quotes). When prompted, enter your normal password. You will see some technical details about attached hard drives. Do you only have one ? Is it listed as /dev/sda ? OK, now for the second thing. Attach the new hard drive and again type 'sudo fdisk -l). Do you now also see details for the second hard drive and is it listed as /dev/sdb ?

Comment: No I don't know how to find the command prompt. I'm sorry it has to be that basic.

Comment: This is in no way a sarcastic comment, I am genuinely trying to be constructiove. If you can't open a command prompt I'm not sure you'll know how to open and view the files on the disk. But lets give it a go. Are you running from an Ubuntu live CD ?

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+T to open command prompt

Comment: If you are, and you are now at the desktop, press the windows key. The dashboard should open. In the search box type "Files" (without the quotes). Do you see a folder icon called "Files" ? If you do, click it and the file manager should open. Do you see your hard drive listed in the panel on the left hand side ?

Comment: In fact, easier still, in the column on the left hand side of the desktop do you see a filing cabinet icon ? If so, click it. This is also the file manager. (I don't use unity so I am doing this from memory !!)

Comment: I have file manager open and I can see Places, Devices and Network. Under devices all the installed drive are visible except for the drive I need

Comment: I also used Tim's suggestion to open the command prompt

Comment: Hopefully we can take this up again around the same time tomorrow.

Comment: Okay. in the command prompt type `ls /media/<USERNAME>`. Change <USERNAME> to you username.

Comment: The other Ask Ubuntu question you mention, [is it this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21987/not-enough-components-to-start-the-raid-array/21990#21990)?

Comment: Please correct ls /media/<USERNAME>.Change <nick> or ls /media/<nick>

Comment: Thank you all very much. The answer from Oli worked like a dream. I now have access to all 750Gb of what I thought I was going to loose. THANKS AGAIN regards, Nick.

Comment: Hi Nick, don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you (click the "V" on the left), otherwise the question will still appear as "unanswered"

Answer (score 1):

[My experience](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21987/not-enough-components-to-start-the-raid-array/21990#21990) of MyBook devices is that they use a type of RAID to provide advanced features.
This can be mounted in Ubuntu, if you know how.

First of all is the easy way. It might work. It might not. In a terminal, run:

```
sudo apt-get install mdadm
```

It'll probably ask you to configure `postfix`, just accept the defaults. Reboot and you might find that you can mount it in Nautilus (the file manager, as you put it) just by clicking the drive it's listing. If you can't, no worries, back to the terminal. Run:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```

Back to the file manager. Has anything popped up? Can you mount it by clicking on it? No? Okay, now we get a little more technical. We need the partition name. Run `sudo fdisk -l` and work out which drive is yours. We're looking for a `/dev/sdXY`-like string. Once you have that, run:

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sdXY
```

Obviously replacing the `XY` with your real value. If that complains about stuff, let us know. If not, the device should be available and showing up in Nautilus.